# Developing a Video conferencing application where the participants should have a feature to show their video only to organizer using Microsoft TEAMS

Tags: .net, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to develop a Video Conferencing application using Microsoft Graph API for TEAMS.

My requirement for it is

- Participant should be given an option to show his/her video only to organizer but not other participants in the meeting.

Could anyone please help me to know whether this is possible via Microsoft TEAMS API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank you @ChetanSharma-msft

Answer (score 0):

your requirements leave quite a bit to the imagination, but
I would recommend using a combination of [Azure Communication Services and Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/teams-interop).

- Using the ACS part you can build a custom service that where you have the freedom and responsibility to build your own client.
- You could build an ACS client that sets up a video-call with a ACS router
- the Router ( another ACS Client) implements the logic which video stream to send where.
- The router then can send the the selected streams ACS-Teams Interop to a Teams Meeting.

Note that you will need to build the (multi-tier) logic yourself, depending on the authentication/licensing of your clients, you will may incur charges for the use of the ACS service.